# Replacing soft returns with hard returns

Tags: automation

I have hundreds of Word documents (.doc, .docx, and .rtf only) downloading continuously into hundreds of subfolders, all in one main folder, and for some reason all of them have soft returns (^l or manual line breaks) where there should be hard returns (^p or paragraph marks).  Is there a program or a script which can use "new file" as an event trigger and replace all the soft returns with hard returns for every new file that downloads into any subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [FileSystemWatcher class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) from any .NET language (e.g. C#, VB.NET, F#, IronPython), listening to the [Created event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created(v=vs.110).aspx). Once you know that a file has been added, you could then use the Word object model to open and reformat the document, just as you are doing in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178997/soft-returns-macro).